# Confusion on Time.toMillis(boolean)

Tags: android, time

My Time objects toString() returns **19700101T000000America/New_York(4,0,0,0,18000)**

The fields are as below:

```
allDay - false
gmtOff - 0
hour - 0
isDst - -1
Min - 0
Month - 0
MonthDay - 1
Second - 0
TimeZone - America/New_York
Year - 0
YearDay - 1970
```

But when I am using **Time.toMillis(false)**, its always returns a value larger than 0. As the time represents **1970, 1st Jan**, I want the value 0 to be returned. Even the **second** field of object is also having 0 in it. But still a different value.

How do I solve this?

Comment: The basis for the world's civil time is not the US, but UTC: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the time zone you have chosen is America/New_York. 
The time zone should be GMT for it to return 0 value.

The toMillis method will return the number of milliseconds since epoch. Epoch is 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC(GMT).

Comment: If I will use Time.isEpoch(), will it return true?

Comment: It will be equal to epoch if you change your time object's time zone to GMT.

Comment: When constructing the time object you can use Time t = new Time("UTC");